# How to redirect a short URL to a long more descriptive URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I would like to provide users a short URL www.example.com/books/DOP/ and have them redirected to www.example.com/Books/Daughters-of-the-Pioneers-Autobiographies/index.html. The purpose is to save the user from having to type the full url.

I tried creating a razor page as follows with the redirect on the OnGet with no success. Any thoughts?

```
namespace SLCore21.Pages.Books.DOP
{
    public class indexModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {
           LocalRedirectPermanent("~/Books/Daughters-of-the-Pioneers-Autobiographies/index.html"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, are you trying to map the url `.../books/DOP` with `.../index.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the approach you're using to work, you need to return the result of `LocalRedirectPermanent`, which also requires changing the signature of the `OnGet` handler to return e.g. an `IActionResult`. Here's an updated example:

```
public IActionResult OnGet()
{
    return LocalRedirectPermanent("~/Books/Daughters-of-the-Pioneers-Autobiographies/index.html"); 
}
```

Using a dedicated Razor Page for this might be a little excessive: I would introduce a custom middleware that uses a map of source to destination and perform such redirects there. Here's an example middleware function to demonstrate how this might work:

```
var redirectMap = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    ["/books/dop"] = "/Books/Daughters-of-the-Pioneers-Autobiographies/index.html"
};

app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
    if (redirectMap.TryGetValue(
        ctx.Request.Path.ToString().TrimEnd('/').ToLower(),
        out var redirectPath))
    {
        ctx.Response.Redirect(redirectPath, true);
        return;
    }

    await next();
});
```

I've added a hardcoded `redirectMap` here, but I'd move this to configuration if this is something that was going to change regularly enough.

The code itself is simple enough - it looks at the incoming request, strips trailing `/`s from the path, converts it to lowercase and then checks if the value exists in `redirectMap`. If it does exist, the code just performs a redirect (the `true` is for permanent) and short-circuits the pipeline. Otherwise, execution is passed on to the next middleware.

Comment: Kirk, this is very helpful. Thank you for your time. Where (before/after) in the following Configure pipeline should I place the code: app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();

Comment: I'd add it before `app.UseStaticFiles()`.